# how to enable http access on ZyXEL VMG8924-B10A using PuTTY

Tags: putty, zyxel

A while ago I accidentally disabled HTTP access on my ZyXEL router(I thought I was disabling it on a different router but it redirected me).

A year has now past and I forgot about it but now I need to port forward something. I have tried port forwarding on putty but it doesn't seem to work. please can somebody guide me on how to do this! thanks.

Comment: Does https work ? resetting the device is a option ?

Comment: if i reset it then i will have to call my isp